# How to parse multi dimension array into Talend

Tags: talend

I have array which I need to parse into Talent

```
{
    "sEcho": 1,
    "iTotalRecords": 54,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 54,
    "aaData": [
        [
            "79",
            "testowy2",
            "testowy samochod",
            "12.00",
            "14.00",
            "2147483647",
            "posciel",
            ""
        ]
    ]
}
```

What would be Xpath Query which I need to pass on the tExtractJSONFields ?

Answer (score 1):

you might use JSONPath query to read the multi dimensional array via tExtractJSONFields.

For query building (with respect to above data), please refer below screen shot :

[image: tInputFileJson]

[image: tExtractJsonFields]

you will get the array in "id" field.

Let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this,

**"Please check right XPathExpression or XML source document."** error is occuring...

Your input is a valid json but not a valid XML Document